# html email table element not inline in outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

I have a email template table with another table inside it for a two column width style layout. Problem is that the table is rendering correctly in all but outlook 365. What's weird is that in outlook online it renders out fine. I'm completely stumped and need some help.

Code is:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wrapper" style="background-color: #414d7e;" width="600"><!--section-5-->
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="break2" style="background-color: #ffffff; border-collapse: collapse;" width="296">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><img src="https://admin.gurgl.co.uk/site_assets/warwick_windows/images/warwick-installed-vertical-window.jpg" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block; vertical-align: middle;" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="break2" width="296" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="25"><img alt="" height="1" src="https://admin.gurgl.co.uk/site_assets/warwick_windows/images/spacer.gif" title="" width="1" /></td>
                                            <td valign="top">
                                            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td height="10"><img alt="" height="1" src="https://admin.gurgl.co.uk/site_assets/warwick_windows/images/spacer.gif" title="" width="1" /></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top">
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <td align="left" class="editable" data-selector="td.editable" style="font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; font-size: 23px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 1.1; padding-top: 10px;">Our Vertical Sliders include</td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="20"><img alt="" height="1" src="https://admin.gurgl.co.uk/site_assets/warwick_windows/images/spacer.gif" title="" width="1" /></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td><img alt="" height="3" src="https://admin.gurgl.co.uk/site_assets/warwick_windows/images/white-line.jpg" title="" width="30" /></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td class="editable" data-selector="td.editable">
                                                                    <ul style="padding-top: 20px; margin-top: 2px; color: #ffffff; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 26px; list-style-type: none;">
                                                                        <li>&bull;&nbsp;10 Day turn around</li>
                                                                        <li>&bull;&nbsp;10% off your first order</li>
                                                                        <li>&bull;&nbsp;7 Colours from stock</li>
                                                                        <li>&bull;&nbsp;Timeless Elegance looks</li>
                                                                        <li>&bull;&nbsp;Built in Security bar</li>
                                                                        <li>&bull;&nbsp;Made in our Sheffield Factory</li>
                                                                    </ul>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td height="15"><img alt="" height="1" src="https://admin.gurgl.co.uk/site_assets/warwick_windows/images/spacer.gif" title="" width="1" /></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="20"><img alt="" height="1" src="https://admin.gurgl.co.uk/site_assets/warwick_windows/images/spacer.gif" title="" width="1" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="break2" style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="600">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td height="100" style="width: 100%; display: block; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 26px; text-align:center;" width="600">We match any like for like quote</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <!--[if mso]>
                        <td align="center">
                      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://www.warwicktradewindows.co.uk/products.php?cat=118" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="0%" stroke="0" fillcolor="#414d7e">
                        <w:anchorlock/>
                        <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;">
                          Read more
                        </center>
                      </v:roundrect>
                      </td>
                      <![endif]-->
                      <![if !mso]>
                        <td style="width: 100%; display: block; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; text-align:center;" width="600"><a href="http://www.warwicktradewindows.co.uk/products.php?cat=118" style="background-color: #414d7e; padding: 8px 10px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; text-align: center;">Read more</a></td>
                        </td>
                    <![endif]>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="30"><img alt="" height="1" src="https://admin.gurgl.co.uk/site_assets/warwick_windows/images/spacer.gif" title="" width="1" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!--section-5--end-->
</tbody>
```

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/fsc71og6/

Comment: add screenshot of outlook 365 issue

Comment: https://emily-switchstanceit.tinytake.com/sf/MzExMDk0XzE4NDc4NTc

Comment: Have added a link to an image, meant 10 badge not rep :)

Comment: Tried that before posted here and it didn't work.

Comment: Instead of using two tables, use one table with two td's for 2 columns

Comment: Had top rebuild the table and it works. didn't want to ha ha